# Why does a data value logged to the console work, but not when assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Javascript newbie here. Trying to set up the new Stripe checkout V3. I need to get a session id from HTML to my Javascript in Rails.

HTML file:

```
<%= content_tag :div, id: "temp_information", data: {temp: @session.id} do %>
<% end %>
<div data-stripe="<%= @session.id %>">
<button id="checkout-button">Pay</button>
</div>
```

Javascript file:

```
var ses_id = $('#temp_information').data('temp');
alert(ses_id);
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
  // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
  // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
  sessionId: ses_id
}).then(function (result) {
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
  // error, display the localized error message to your customer
  // using `result.error.message`.
});
```

I get undefined for ses_id.
When i do

```
$('#temp_information').data('temp');
```

in the console it shows the correct output. But when I do:

```
var a = $('#temp_information').data('temp');
```

Then I get undefined in the console. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, JavaScript works on rendered HTML. Until we can see exactly what your back-end template is putting out we're guessing. Please get rid of your Ruby markup and show us what the browser sees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
*my code*
)};
```

To wait for everything to load before trying to access values. I think this is because of Rails or Turbolinks. Not totally sure which.

Answer (score 0):

$.data(parameter) is used to store information and $.data() is used to get all data stored, so you just need to remove 'temp to get data.

```
var a = $('#temp_information').data();
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: .data() just returned the object {temp: 'foo'}. Solved the problem eventually. Needed to use $document.ready. Thanks for your reply!